# Почему некоторые люди отвечают на вопрос в комментариях?

Tags: поддержка, комментарии

Ведь автор потом не сможет подтвердить правильный ответ.

Comment: зато автор может написать свой собственный ответ :-)

Comment: Бывает, что ответ такой элементарный, что заслуживает только комментария.

Comment: Еще бывает, что вопрос не совсем понятен, а ответ, в котором будет ключевое слово "возможно", не охота давать, то в виде предположения пишешь в комментариях.